# Getting Select Tag to work as a on click function in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

So I have this tab set up that works as on click links in desktop, but in tablet and mobile, I need it to be a select drop down list with the same functionality.

Here is the code for it on desktop as links:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

        // Show/Hide Tabs
        $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

        // Change/remove current tab to active
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active-tab').siblings().removeClass('active-tab');

        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

This works perfect, now this is what I have for the select tag:

```
$('.tabs .tab-select select').on('change', function(e)    {  
    var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('option');

    $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

});
```

How can I get the select tag code to work?

Comment: Can you share a JSfiddle.

Comment: Try using the jQuery focus handler: [link](https://api.jquery.com/focus/)

Comment: I tried focus no luck @ohio818

Comment: Here is the fiddle @Ahmad Baktash Hayeri   https://jsfiddle.net/f22nx4wz/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to do `$('.tabs .tab-select select')` (which means *take the select tag that is a child of .tab-select*) because the `select` element that you are using has the `.tab-select` class itself.

Secondly, `$(this).attr('option')` is undefined inside your change handler, as it refers to a `select` *attribute* (no HTML tag has a select attribute) in the select element itself.

**Workaround**: To get the current *option* that was *selected*, you should make use of [jQuery's `:selected` Selector](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/), and concatenating the option's value (or the text) to the *tab's* id as such:

```
$('.tabs .tab-select').on('change', function(e){
       var currentOption = $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + ' option:selected').text();
       $('#tab' + currentOption).show().siblings().hide();
});
```

***[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/hg44c06g/)***.

Comment: It works great in the JS Fiddle, but when I add it in to the overall JQuery it doesn't work

Comment: Did you change your _selector_ from `$('.tabs .tab-select select')` to `$('.tabs .tab-select')`

Comment: Yes i did. It doesn't work integrated into the full code @Ahmad Baktash Hayeri

Comment: `console.log()` something in the `handler` to see if it is actually triggered.

Answer (score 0):

It works great in the JS Fiddle, but when I add it in to the overall JQuery it doesn't work

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       $('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

         ////Show/Hide Tabs
       $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

     ////Change/remove current tab to active
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active-tab').siblings().removeClass('active-tab');

    e.preventDefault();
});////desktop

$('.tabs .tab-select').on('change', function(e){
       var currentOption = $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + ' option:selected').text();
       $('#tab' + currentOption).show().siblings().hide();

});////mobile
```

});////end of JQuery block